# ForEach giving Invalid Cast at Runtime

Tags: c#, linq, types, foreach

I have the following:

```
 foreach (ItemOption itemOption in p.Items.Select(e => e.ItemOption).GroupBy(e => e.Id))
  { // do some work on itemoptions }
```

This compiles.
However at runtime I get an Invalid Cast exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping[System.String,MyNameSpace.ItemOption]' to type 'MyNameSpace.ItemOption'.

If I change the code to, e.g. a String as the type of the item :

```
 foreach (String itemOption in p.Items.Select(e => e.ItemOption).GroupBy(e => e.Id))
  { // do some work on itemoptions }
```

Then the compiler tells me the types are incompatible.

**Why doesn't the compiler flag the type incompatibility in the first code block?**

---

I did some further investigation and found that, given the following code:

```
var foo = p.Items.Select(e => e.ItemOption).GroupBy(e => e.Id));
Type singleElementType = foo.ElementAt(0).GetType();
```

`singleElementType` is:

> System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.String, MyNamespace.ItemOption]

---

**UPDATE**
Following on from the answers I have put together a simpler case to demonstrate the issue

Given the objects:

```
interface IMyObj
{
    string Id;
}

class MyObj : IMyObj
{
    public string Id;
    public MyObj2 cg;
}

class MyObj2
{
}
```

This will fail at compile time

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> compileTimeFailList = new List<MyObj>()
foreach (MyObj2 myObj2 in compileTimeFailList.Where(x => x.Id != null))
{
```

and this will fail at run time

```
IEnumerable<IMyObj> runtimeFailList = new List<IMyObj>();
foreach (MyObj2 myObj2 in runtimeFailList.Where(x => x.Id != null))
{
```

The reason being that the objects in `runtimeFailList` may extend MyObj2 and this cannot be determined by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ItemOption` is presumably not a sealed class (unlike System.String) so it's possible that the result of `p.Items.Select(...).GroupBy(...)` would be implementations of `IGrouping<...>` which were *also* `ItemOption` values. The compiler can't know, so it inserts an implicit cast. As `string` doesn't implement `IGrouping<...>` and is sealed, the compiler can spot that that's definitely a mistake.

`foreach` has *always* included a cast where necessary. It's a bit nasty, because it's hidden... but without it, `foreach` would have been very painful to use pre-generics.

Now as for why it's *actually* wrong... each item in the result is going to be a grouping rather than an individual item. Let me know if you need more help working with the results.

Comment: Thanks, that is clearer.  You are correct that `ItemOption` is not a sealed class.

Comment: I've updated my question with a simpler case to illustrate the issue and make sure I have understood the explanation correctly

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530748/new-fxcop-rule-for-net2-on-foreach-in-non-generic-ienumerable

Answer (score 1):

Its because class String cannot be inherited, but your class ItemOption can be inherited and also can be casted implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

About why the cast fails:

```
foreach (ItemOption itemOption in p.Items.Select(e => e.ItemOption).GroupBy(e => e.Id))
```

Your `.GroupBy` doesn't return a list of ItemOptions, bunched by id. Rather it returns a list-of-lists: the first list contains all separate `Id`s and for each Id there is a list of `ItemOption`s with the same Id.